# Issue parsing HTML with react code in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, cheerio

We have created a Webpack loader internally to manipulate/inject some common HTML code within other project's index.html.

Below is a sample React html template -

```
let source = `<html>
  <body>
     <div id="root">
        <%- reactServerSideRender %>
     <div>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

Below is the code using Cheerio.

```
import * as $ from 'cheerio';
console.log('After cheerio', source);
let $source = $.load(source);
console.log('After cheerio', $source);
```

Expected result -

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="root">
        <%- reactServerSideRender %>
     <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actual Result

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="root">
        <%- reactserversiderender="" %="">
        </%->
     <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Update 1/7/19: I was able to trace the issue back to 
https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer/blob/master/index.js#L82

For my above code, it is being recognized as a TAG (i logged below values from the `elem` variable.

```
element type      - tag
element attribute - { reactserversiderender: '', '%': '' }
element name      - %-
```

This issue was due to htmlparser2 module used by cheerio not parsing the html correctly.

SOLUTION: I was able to fix the issue after using parse5 module (Cheerio is also planning to make parse5 default parser for the project but it is not release yet). Below are extra lines of code i had to add to make it work.

```
const document = parse5.parse(source);
const str = parse5.serialize(document);
const $source = $.load(str);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). You want to parse this template, but you haven't told us why or what end result you want. FWIW thatisn't React code at all; it looks like [EJS](https://ejs.co/) or some other templating language that uses similar syntax.

Comment: It was the ejs file that we were trying to run though our loader before  passing it to HTML Webpack plugin. Inside our loader we were using Cheerio to manipulate the DOM which is code i posted above which was not parsing the template correctly.

Comment: Solutions shouldn't be edited into the question.  Please make that a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).